# How to close active jQuery tools tabs?

Tags: jquery, tabs

I am using jQuery Tools tabs, and I want to be able to close any active tab when I click on it, so that all tabs become inactive.
This is my [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/r527afoa/1/).

Comment: could use destroy and then initialize again

Comment: How am I able to do that? @charlietfl

Answer (score 1):

Add this function:

```
$("li").click(function() {
  $(this).remove();
  $("div.panes > div").remove();
});
```

If you want to remove the `div.panes > div` one by one, try:

```
$("li").click(function() {
  var i = $('li').index(this);
  $("div.panes > div").eq(i).remove();
  $(this).remove();
});
```

Try this to hide the elements:

```js
$( "li" ).click(function() {
 var i = $('li').index(this);
 var divs = $("div.panes > div");
 for (var j=0;j<divs.length;j++) {
   if (j == i) {
     if ($("div.panes > div").eq(i).css('display') == 'none') {
         $("div.panes > div").eq(i).css("display", "block"); 
     } else {
         $("div.panes > div").eq(i).css("display", "none");   
     }
   } else {
     $("div.panes > div").eq(j).css("display", "none");
   }
 }
});
```

```css
/* root element for tabs  */
ul.tabs {
    margin:0 !important;
    padding:0;
    height:30px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #666;
}

/* single tab */
ul.tabs li {
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type:none;
}

/* link inside the tab. uses a background image */
ul.tabs a {
    float:left;
    font-size:13px;
    display:block;
    padding:5px 30px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border:1px solid #666;
    border-bottom:0px;
    height:18px;
    background-color:#efefef;
    color:#777;
    margin-right:2px;
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
    outline:0;
    -moz-border-radius:4px 4px 0 0;
}

ul.tabs a:hover {
    background-color:#F7F7F7;
    color:#333;
}

/* selected tab */
ul.tabs a.current {
    background-color:#ddd;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
    color:#000;
    cursor:default;
}


/* tab pane */
.panes div {
    display:none;
    border:1px solid #666;
    border-width:0 1px 1px 1px;
    min-height:150px;
    padding:15px 20px;
    background-color:#ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
  </ul>
 
  <!-- tab "panes" -->
  <div class="panes">
    <div>pane 1 content</div>
    <div>pane 2 content</div>
    <div>pane 3 content</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I didn't mean that I want to destroy the tab. I meant, I want to be able to close it, so that no other tab remains active, and I can reopen any tab later. @JuanSedano

Comment: There is still a problem with the code. I have to click a tab twice to open it. And if a tab is opened and I click on another tab, it doesn't open immediately, but it closes the open tab. Can this code be modified so that, if a tab is opened, and I click on it, it closes immediately, and if I click on another tab it opens immediately? @JuanSedano